# Proper way to trigger a flow retry?

Tags: apache-nifi

Consider this flow:

[image: Flow]

It's a simple flow to authenticate to an HTTP API and handle success/failure. In the failure state, you can see I added a `ControlRate` processor and that there are 2 FlowFiles in the queue for it. I have it set to only pass one FlowFile every 30 seconds (`Time Duration = 30sec` `Maximum Rate = 1`). So the queue will continue to fill during this, if the authentication process continues to fail.

What I want is to essentially drop all but the first FlowFile in this queue, because I don't want it to continue re-triggering the authentication processor after we get a successful authentication.

I believe I can accomplish this by setting the `FlowFile Expiration` (on the highlighted queue) to be just longer than the 30 second `Time Duration` of the `ControlRate` processor.  But this seems a bit arbitrary and not quite correct in my mind.

**Is there a way to say "take first, drop rest" for the highlighted queue?**

Comment: I would make /token as a separate process that does not depend on main flow that is using generated token. Normally token is alive during predictable amount of time, so, you could generate flow file for token with a period you need for token and store it as a variable or in distributed cache.

Comment: This entire process is only related to getting the token. In the `POST /token` process, it should persist the cookies which would be auto-used in subsequent `InvokeHTTP` processes to make authenticated calls. So this entire process is just to ensure there's always a valid token/cookie. The `Generate JSON Payload` process is set to run every X minutes e.g. a but before the token would expire.

Comment: I think I got this working correctly by configure all relationships from `Generate JSON Payload` through `ControlRate` have a `Backpressure` set to allow only 1 FlowFile.